# Tastypie: Why is "pk" field in response when doing PUT?

Tags: django, tastypie

I have this ModelResource:

```
class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
    id = fields.IntegerField('id', readonly=True)

    def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
        return data['objects']


    class Meta:
        queryset = Project.objects.all()
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        resource_name = 'projects'
        include_resource_uri = False
        #fields = ['id', 'title', 'date_created', 'date_modified']
        excludes = []
        always_return_data = True

        authorization = Authorization()
```

When I do GET /projects/1 or POST /projects response is:

```
'{
"date_created": "2012-08-29T16:47:55.417000+00:00", 
"date_modified": "2012-08-29T16:47:55.417000+00:00", 
"id": 1, 
"title": "1st Testing Project"
}'
```

but when I do PUT /projects response is:

```
'{
"date_created": "2012-08-29T16:47:55.417000+00:00", 
"date_modified": "2012-09-05T18:58:39.746336+00:00", 
"id": 1, 
"pk": "1", 
"title": "EDITED project"
}'
```

So there is additional "pk" field. How did it get there? How do I get rid of it? It's there only when doing PUT. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps try using 'pk' as the attribute in `id = fields.IntegerField('id', readonly=True)` rather than 'id' which is kind of internal and is perhaps fooling Tastypie somehow?

Comment: May I ask why you have the field id in the Resource in first place? Isn't it suppose to be the Project id? If you remove your "id" field from the resource do you get the same results?

Comment: I put it there because I found somewhere that Tastypie ignores auto-generated fields, later I found out it's not case anymore. But I get same results when I remove it.